# Retrieve Facebook User's Timeline Data

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

To elaborate the subject line, I want to create an **FB app** or **FB Connect** that will fetch a **user's historical data which he/she shared on FB**; eg: fetch with whom user have made friendship in particular year or what statuses user have shared in a particular year. *In short, retrieving users activities since he/she joined the FB till current date*.
**This is similar to what we can see in our timeline**.

Is this possible to grab those info using graph api? I spend a day in searching a help for this but didn't found any.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Very new to the Timeline and Open Graph thing.

Any help/suggestion would surely be appreciated.

I'm using PhP as the coding language.

Thanks in advance,

Javed.

Answer (score 0):

should be possible but via the open graph api, see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

**Graph Api != Open Graph**

Comment: Thanks Rufinus.I know Graph Api is different than Open Graph